# Cooperatively coping with the [co-op] coop - can we agree on a single tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

There's irony to be found here.

- [**[co-op]**](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/co-op) - 6 questions about cooperative multiplayer gameplay.
- [**[cooperative-mode]**](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cooperative-mode) - 4 questions about cooperative multiplayer gameplay.

We also had a short-lived **[coop-mode]**, but that was converted to the latter.

I can't find much reason to keep these tags, and any variants thereof, separate. They're always going to be equally applicable in referencing to the cooperative aspects of a game; whether the coop is present as a separate mode or is the default seems largely irrelevant, if not needlessly complex, as far as tagging is concerned.

Can we think of a good reason to have separate tags for now and in the future? If not, can we agree on a single tag to use?

Comment: I like Co-op and only Co-op personally.

Comment: Would `[coop]` sound weird?

Comment: @LessPop Feel free to propose that as an answer.

Comment: I vote we call it [multiplayerwhere2playersplayingacampaigntogetherandnotagainstotherplayers]

Comment: @badp Personally speaking, I can quickly parse out when a sentence is talking about chicken houses versus mutual cahoots, so I don't think it sounds weird. I suggest making that an answer if you want to suggest that as our unified tag.

Comment: @Grace, I'm just afraid it may read as "coup". I'm not the greatest English pronouncer ever.

Comment: @Badp that's a brilliant idea, let's use coup and then use it as a honey pot for malcontents!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[Co-op] seems like the best choice here. In general, I prefer a shorter tag when a longer one doesn't convey any additional information, the - improves readability, and extending it to cooperative mode, or adding the word 'mode' in general adds nothing to the tag.

Comment: That about sums up my thoughts.

Comment: +1 ` ` ` ` ` ` ` `

Comment: Enough games use Co-op that it seems fine, what's more there is no collision with another abbreviation.

Comment: Vote up the synonym [here](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/tags/co-op/synonyms).

Comment: @Call: **ding**

Comment: Co-op it is! I have performed a merge with the provided synonym.